# Alternate parameterization of a line

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

There are several ways to specify a line. In Mathematica's graphics, it is done by specifying two points and then connecting the points with the `Line` command. But it is sometimes desirable to parameterize a line, and the most familiar way is the form $y = m x + b$ where $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the offset. This parameterization is particularly awkward for near-vertical lines (where the slope becomes near infinite and numerically sensitive). An alternative is the $(\rho, \theta)$ parameterization which specifies the line as an angle $\theta$ and a distance $\rho$ from the origin, as shown in [the theory section of this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform). The gist is that the line consists of all points $x$ and $y$ for which $\rho = x \cos(\theta) + y \sin(\theta)$, essentially a conversion to polar coordinates.

Here is a function which takes a pair of points `{p1, p2}` as input in the form `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}` and outputs the corresponding $\rho$ and $\theta$:

```
linePolar[{p1_, p2_}] := Module[{},
    {rx, ry} = Rationalize[p1]; {sx, sy} = Rationalize[p2];
    sol = Solve[{rx Cos[t] + ry Sin[t] == rho, 
             sx Cos[t] + sy Sin[t] == rho}, {rho, t}] // N;
    First[Select[{rho, t} //. sol //. C[1] -> 0, #[[1]] >= 0 &]]];
```

For example:

```
linePolar[{{0, -1}, {-1, 0}}]
{0.707107, -2.35619}
```

which shows that the line connecting the two points is `Sqrt[2]/2` away from the origin at an angle of -135 degrees. The almost vertical line

```
linePolar[{{1, -1}, {1.1, 1}}]
{1.04869, -0.0499584}
```

has slope near zero, and the answer appears to be nicely behaved numerically as the line crosses vertical.

I have two questions. First, it bothers me that the function is essentially re-solving the system of equations each time it is called, and this must be inefficient. Is there a nice way to make it only do the solution once? Second, I would like to have an "inverse" for this function -- something that would take a pair of $(\rho, \theta)$ values and allow it to be plotted. This would be useful because many subsequent calculations need to occur in the $(\rho, \theta)$ space, and it would be good to be able to visualize this by plotting.

Comment: To be clear are we talking about (infinite) lines, or line segments here?

Comment: The question is really about (full) lines, though of course we can only ever plot portions of them. This is why I enclosed inverse in scary quotes -- you can't really get back to the particular specified endpoints, only back to the line itself.

Comment: No time to get into this today but it *seems* like a variation of a relatively common rectangular to polar conversion.  I presume you've already looked at such things; wherein lies the difference and difficulty?

Comment: Here's a decent reference I believe: http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/formulas/faq.polar.html

Comment: Clearly this is related -- the form I used above is included in the "General Form of the line" section. There is a bit of a step between this and a usable function. Nice reference.

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? It's not clear why you would prefer the polar parametrization over e.g. `p1 + t*(p2-p1)` where p1 and p2 are the given points in R^2 and t is the parameter. Is it that you have a particular need for the distance from the origin?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Not every form is useful but also those not useful are taught in school. So nice way to handle transformations between those forms are useful. I think it is great question in context of education.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - The underlying problem (where this arose) is a bit complicated (which is why I abstracted out this part of it). Basically there are sets of (noisy) near-vertical line segments. I am trying to estimate the "distances" between the segments, and match the various sets  together. The angles of the lines are key, and so the $(\rho, \theta)$ parameterization is particularly apt.

Comment: Ah. Starting to make more sense. By "match" you want segemnts that lie on (approximately) the same line? (But allowing them to be far apart as segments?). Or are you looking for segments that are close together AND have close angles? I'm still not following quite what you want, although it is now more clear that this parametrization will be useful for obtaining it.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - picture a large sieve with lots of near-vertical lines. What I have is many small impressions that might come from this sieve (or might come from another sieve altogether). The goal is to find out where the pieces come from -- to find where the pattern of vertical lines in the impressions best fits the pattern of lines in the sieve. If this project ever reaches maturity, I will link back here with a full description.

Comment: I assume you have in mind the colander type of sieve. Does it have some symmetry to it? For example, do extruded segments, if extended, meet at a point or at least have a common axis? That could make the matching task easier (assuming I understand that task).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau -- here's an example of such a sieve called chain lines used in paper making: http://mywingsbooks.com/coll-terms/pprlaid_.shtml

Comment: @bills, "Is there a nice way to make it only do the solution once?" - have you tried memoization: f[..] := g[..] = h[..]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Cross` product is very useful here. It can be used with 3D vectors to get the perpendicular distance of a line to the origin, but it also works with a 2D vector  as an easy way to specify its perpendicular:

This function returns the radial distance $\rho$ and the angle $\theta$ as in the question, but doesn't require resolving the coordinates of the given points explicitly:

```
lineToPolar[{p1_, p2_}] := 
 {
  Abs[#], ArcTan @@ Cross[Sign[#] (p2 - p1)]} &@
  Last[Apply[Cross, PadRight[#, 3] & /@ {p1, Normalize[p1 - p2]}]]    

lineToPolar[{{0, -1}, {-1, 0}}]

(* ==> {1/Sqrt[2], -((3 Pi)/4)} *)

Simplify[
 lineToPolar[{{x, y}, {u, v}}], {x, y, u, v} ∈ Reals]
```

> $$\begin{array}{c}\{\frac{\left| v x-u y\right|}{\sqrt{(u-x)^2+(v-y)^2}},\\\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(v-y) \text{sgn}(v x-u y)}{\sqrt{\text{sgn}\left((u-x)^2+(v-y)^2\right)}},\frac{(u-x) \text{sgn}(u y-v x)}{\sqrt{\text{sgn}\left((u-x)^2+(v-y)^2\right)}}\right)\}\end{array}$$

This is the general formula for the polar representation. You could use this directly to define the conversion function if desired.

To optimize the conversion function some more, the component form of the given vectors could be used together with this form, where the `Sign` function has been turned into a case distinction:

```
FullSimplify[
  lineToPolar[{{x, y}, {u, v}}], {x, y, u, v} ∈ Reals] /. 
 Indeterminate -> 0
```

> $$\{\frac{\left| v x-u y\right|
>    }{\sqrt{(u-x)^2+(v-y)^2}},
> \begin{cases}
>  0 & v x=u y \\
>  \tan ^{-1}(v-y,x-u) & u y<v x \\
>  \tan ^{-1}(y-v,u-x) & \text{True} \\
> \end{cases}
> \}$$

**Edit:**

In an earlier version, the parameter $\rho$ was allowed to be negative if the order of `p1` and `p2` was reversed. That means $\rho$ is the 2D *impact parameter* of the line, but for a real *polar coordinate* you may want to require $\rho>0$. In the above code, I make sure that when the impact parameter is negative we exchange the order of `p1` and `p2` to get back to a positive $\rho$.

**End edit**

The inverse is even simpler:

```
Clear[ρ, θ]; 
lineFromPolar[ρ_, θ_] = 
 Function[{t}, {t, ρ}.#] &[RotationMatrix[Pi/2 - θ]]

With[{ρ = 1/2, θ = 3 Pi/4},
 ParametricPlot[lineFromPolar[ρ, θ][t], {t, -10, 10}]
 ]
```

[image: plot]

Here I used the fact that the offset from the origin is specified by a vector perpendicular to the line, of length $\rho$. This required orthogonality is provided automatically by the rows of `RotationMatrix`.

Comment: I have never checked that `Cross` works that way too and that `ArcTan` has this handy extension. And I should have! :) +1

Comment: A fine answer, however your `lineFromPolar` is not written efficiently.  You should evaluate the body of the function:  `lineFromPolar2[ρ_, θ_] := Evaluate[{#, ρ}.RotationMatrix[-θ]] &`.  Timing for your method: `lineFromPolar[1.4, 0.3] /@ RandomReal[9, 150000] // Timing // First` is 0.936 seconds; and for mine is 0.01436 seconds.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You're right, I didn't think about efficiency in the inverse. The version in my edit is even faster than yours now.

Comment: @Jens -- thanks for looking at this. I think there is still a `Pi` (or maybe `Pi/2`) confusion somewhere. If we take `lineToPolar[{{1, -1}, {1, 1}}]` (note that this is a vertical line that connects these two points) then you get `{-1, Pi}`. But this is a horizontal line, as you can see by putting it into `lineFromPolar`.

Comment: @bills Oh sorry, I used different definitions of $\theta$ for the two functions. What do you prefer: is $\theta$ the angle of the actual line with the horizontal? Or is it the angle of the *normal* to the line with the horizontal, as in the article you [linked here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform)? I have to change one or the other, but I'll wait until you let me know which you like better...

Comment: @Jens -- I've been using the angle to the normal, so would prefer that convention. Thanks again!

Comment: @bills OK, I've changed `lineToPolar` so that angles of `Pi` or `0` are now describing vertical lines, which is what `lineFromPolar` was already assuming.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I double-checked with the same test you did, and mine is consistently faster on version 9: Set `r = RandomReal[9, 150000];` and then `lineFromPolar2[1.4, 0.3] /@ r // Timing // First`. It yields `0.021555` for your function and `0.018534` for mine.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Regarding localization: that's fine, but what I did instead also works. I put $\rho$ into a `Clear` just for completeness now, but actually that isn't even needed, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Evaluating `lineToPolar[{{1,-1},{1.1,1}}]` gives a negative `rho`, and an angle `t` differing by $\pi$ from the OP example. Incorporating a simple `Abs[rho]` and keeping the same angle `t` gives a different line than I think is required. I used

```
lineToPolarAlt[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] :=
   With[{numerator = -y1 x2 + x1 y2},
        {Abs[(numerator)/Norm[{x1, y1} - {x2, y2}]], 
         If[numerator >= 0, Arg[ I x1 - y1 - I x2 + y2], 
                            Arg[-I x1 + y1 + I x2 - y2]]}]
```

to check the two different cases.